# Unexpected Tomcat Shutdown

Tags: windows, tomcat, service, windows-server-2003

Tomcat: 6.0.20.0
OS: Windows Server2003
Architecture: x86
JVM: 1.5.0_19

We have a Tomcat instance that looks to be shutting down unexpectedly. The logs look like the following:

```
[DATE] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
[DATE] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
[DATE] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

There are no exceptions such as out of memory in the logs. It looks like a clean graceful shutdown. The code in our app has been checked for System.exit(). Also nothing should be sending SHUTDOWN to port 8005.

We have a service wrapper in c# that calls a .bat with start/stop commands which in turn call catalina.bat. The service still shows Tomcat as running whenever Tomcat shuts down unexpectedly. The App logs do not log the service shutdown when it's unexpected but logs shutdowns manually done through the service in Windows.

Tomcat Manager is not configured.

Comment: according to the log info you gave, and the fact that the service still shows up as started, tomcat is not shutting down but it is unloading your particular application context.

Comment: I'm sorry, I pasted the wrong piece of the log. It's fixed now.